# on-line tally of unique lines

Tags: shell, awk

`uniq -c` is very useful for counting the number of times the same line appears consecutively

```
$ seq 1 1000 | awk '{ if ($1 > 100 && $1 <= 200) { print "hi" } else {print "bye"} }' | uniq -c

100 bye
100 hi
800 bye
```

However, in order to get a tally for each unique line I have to sort the input first, which seems a bit inefficient.

```
$ seq 1 1000 | awk '{ if ($1 > 100 && $1 <= 200) { print "hi" } else {print "bye"} }' | sort | uniq -c
```

Is there an idiomatic way to tally all occurrences of unique lines using an on-line algorithm?

Comment: I'm sure it's been done in awk with an associative array...

Comment: @JeffSchaller it seems like ```awk '{ count[$0]++ } END { for (key in count) {print key, " ", $count } }'``` does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, you probably meant `count[key]` not `$count`. Also,if you're open to `python`, you could pipe into `python -c 'from collections import Counter; from sys import stdin; c=Counter(stdin); print c'`

Comment: @iroovar. yep, silly typo. unfortunately I can't change it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the input first is about as efficient as it gets.

You can do it with an awk one-liner:

```
awk '{++seen[$0]} END {for (line in count) printf "%7d %s\n", count[line], line}'
```

Which one is more efficient (in memory and CPU time) depends on the data and on the implementation. `sort` is less efficient in theory because it does extra work, but on the other hand it has one job and does it well, whereas awk is a general-purpose tool. If there are a lot of duplicates, awk uses less memory and is probably a little faster. On the other hand, many implementations of sort can cope with huge data sets that don't fit in RAM, whereas awk will just thrash.